# The set $A=\{ x :\|x\|=1 \}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under euclidean norm.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

The set $A=\{ x \mid \|x\|=1 \}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$  is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under Euclidean norm.

If I can show this is closed and bounded then we are done. It seems bounded but I am not sure how to show it is closed.

Comment: Suppose that you have a convergent (in $\Bbb R^n$) sequence of points on the unit sphere. CAn you say anything on the norm of the limit?

Comment: Are you asking about the compactness of every subset of A or about the compactness of A itself?

Answer (score 5):

Just note that every norm is continuous (because 1-lipschitz from the second triangle inequality $|\,||x||-||y||\,|\leq||x-y||$) and then $A=||\cdot||^{-1}(\{1\})$ is a closed set as a reciprocal image of the closed set $\{1\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ by the continuous map $||\cdot||.$

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The following answers  a former version of the question, referring to a *subset* of $S^{n-1}$.

The statement in the title, appearing again in the body of the question, is **wrong**. A subset $$A\subset S^{n-1}\subset {\mathbb R}^n$$ is compact iff it is closed. Consider, e.g., the set
$$A:=\bigl\{x\in{\mathbb R}^n\>\bigm|\>\|x\|=1, \ x_n>0\bigr\}\ .$$
The point $(1,0, \ldots,0)$ is an accumulation point of $A$, but does not belong to $A$.

Comment: What is wrong with the statement?

Comment: @CB note that the question was edited after this answer and before your comment

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not familiar with the topological concept of continuity (that's the answer everyone thinks about). Now, obviously, $A$ is bounded so it suffices to prove that it is in fact closed, that is, its complement is open.

Let $p\in\mathbb R^n\setminus A.$ We shall prove that $p$ is an interior point of $\mathbb R^n\setminus A.$

As $p\notin A$ then $\|p\|\neq1.$ Define $\varepsilon:=|\|p\|-1|.$ Then the open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(p)$ is contained in $\mathbb R^n\setminus A$ (here I used the triangle inequality) Therefore $p$ is an interior point of the complement of $A$ which means that $\mathbb R^n\setminus A$ is open and hence $A$ is closed. Thus $A$ is compact.